# (UWP) Getting xml files from assets folder

Tags: windows, mobile, localization, assets, uwp

I have a "Localization" folder in the "Assets" directory of my UWP project. The folder contains different xml-files that I want to read into a textmanager. When I create a new DirectoryInfo-object like this

```
 new DirectoryInfo("/Assets/Localization");
```

it can't find the directory.
Do I have to pass another root directory prefix for where the app is stored?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should work:

```
 var localizationDirectory = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\Localization");
```

Comment: I tried the same to get the zip file from Assets folder but get some error `The system cannot find the file specified`. Any idea?

Comment: @Kishor Bikram Maybe it is not copied to the assets folder? See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks @gregkalapos. Yes i missed that.